# How to limit the number of characters in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to limit the number of characters displayed to 25 in this anchor tag :

`@Model.Name.Substring(0,25)`

But not all the fields have 25 or greater characters,
so the Substring() complains when there are fewer.
Is there any other way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
@Model.Name.Substring(0,Model.Name.Length > 25 ? 25 : Model.Name.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;   

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SubstringOrFewer(this string str, int n)
    {
        int max = n > str.Length ? str.Length : n;
        return str.Substring(0, max);
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string xx = "0123456789";

        Console.WriteLine(xx.SubstringOrFewer(9));
        Console.WriteLine(xx.SubstringOrFewer(90));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
012345678
0123456789
```

[On DotNetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/8g9Mar)